# AngularJS: ui-select duplicate error

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

In `ui-select-choices repeat="type in (types| filter: $select.search) track by type.name`. In `track by type.name` part, given the `name` is NOT a key. I tried adding two exactly the same data (different key). [Error reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)

Why is it returning a duplicate error?
Why not ui-select just display the two duplicated data since they have different key? Any technical explanation for this?

Comment: It's not like that. I already know what's the cause of error. I just wan't to know why is that an error. Something like that

Comment: ur traking by name .....may be two types contains same name so try with traking by some unique field like id

Comment: That's my question, why is it a duplicate error when it's not a key?

Comment: simply your error message saying it all....there is dup's in repeater.....so its saying to Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.....here you gave name as unique but actually its not  so its saying given the name is NOT a key.

Comment: Ohhwww. That sums it all. Thank you! *cleared mind here*

Answer (score 0):

> Occurs if there are duplicate keys in an ngRepeat expression.
>   Duplicate keys are banned because AngularJS uses keys to associate DOM
>   nodes with items.

From : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes